# android start bluetooth sco not routing mic in lollipop

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, voip, android-bluetooth

In my app through which user can call to any number,im starting the bluetooth through

```
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

it works on all device,but on android 5.0.1 ,
it uses the mic of phone,not the mic of bluetooth headset.
on previous android os,it works,but not on lollipop,only incoming audio is routed to bluetooth headset,but it never uses the bluetooth mic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to disable speaker and make sure that mode is set to normal:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```